# Trying to make a map via Print Layout using an Atlas, but information I request from a particular column is returning values from the wrong column?

Tags: qgis, legend, expression, mapping, atlas

I have a legend in the map atlas where i am trying to return the Date value from the atlas feature (i.e. `[% "Date" %]`, pretty simple) but instead of returning the value stored in the `"Date"` field, it returns the value from the column 2 to the right of the `"Date"` column. *Whatever field I input, it always returns the value from 2 columns over.* (edit: discovered it is not consistently 2 columns over, it appears to be somewhat random with some columns working fine and others not working with no obvious pattern) Does anyone know why this is and what I can do to fix it? I would rather not have to type in "Program" to return the value from the `"Date"` column, etc.

Adding a few screenshots with some censoring for privacy reasons:

[image: Attribute Table for Atlas Feature]
Attribute Table for Atlas Feature

[image: What I require the legend to say, but what I have to type into the expression to achieve it is wrong]
What I require the legend to say, but what I have to type into the expression to achieve it is wrong

[image: What appears in the legend if I type in the correct expression]
What appears in the legend if I type in the correct expression

QGIS version
3.26.1-Buenos Aires

QGIS code revision
b609df9ed4d

Qt version
5.15.3

Python version
3.9.5

GDAL/OGR version
3.5.1

PROJ version
9.0.1

EPSG Registry database version
v10.064 (2022-05-19)

GEOS version
3.10.3-CAPI-1.16.1

SQLite version
3.38.1

PDAL version
2.3.0

PostgreSQL client version
unknown

SpatiaLite version
5.0.1

QWT version
6.1.6

QScintilla2 version
2.13.1

Comment: Can you show a screenshot from the Attribute table with the girls `Date` as well as the one würde the values are returned from?

Comment: I added a few screenshots to try and show what is happening

Comment: Is the atlas layer a temporary table? I've had weird stuff like that happen with a temp layer that went away when I made the layer permanent

Comment: I've also had very similar issues in the past when the file was a shapefile or geojson. Resaving the layer as a geopackage fixed the problems for me.